# How to get the Context from anywhere?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety

In Android, is there any way to get the context of the application of a static way? For example to retrieving it from a background thread.

Thanks

Comment: In general you should pass a Context reference via an argument if you call a method that needs it *(but don't store the reference, it can lead to memory leaks)*. You can also use the Application-Object for this in some circumstances, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987072/using-application-context-everywhere). But keep the limits as described in the answer in mind.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The easiest (and correct) way is:

Define a new class

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    private static MyApp instance;

    public static MyApp getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public static Context getContext(){
        return instance;
        // or return instance.getApplicationContext();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        instance = this;
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

Then in your manifest you need to add this class to the "Name" field at the "Application" tab. Or edit the xml and put

```
<application
    android:name="com.example.app.MyApp"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    .......
    <activity
        ......
```

and then from anywhere you can call

```
MyApp.getContext();
```

Comment: This will work but Just be careful as with using any singleton that you don't abuse it.Read the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context/7298955#7298955) explaining why the ApplicationContext is rarely (though sometimes) the right Context to use.

Best Way:
Unless you simply expose a public method that takes a Context as an argument inside of your classes that require Context (and pass it in from your Activity, etc), this is the way to do it. 
Exp:
public void abc(Context c,int a);
and call it from any activity.

Answer (score 27):

Basically you have 2 types of Context - the *Activity Context* and the [*Application Context*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext%28%29).

It's not necessary to use only one Context for everything. There's problems if you use one Context in every case you need Context. 
It's best to follow something like this - use *Activity Context* inside the Activity and the *Application Context* when passing a context beyond the scope of an Activity, which will help you to avoid [memory leaks](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html).

If you read this article you can see the difference between to the two Context.

> The *Application context* will live as long as your application is alive
>   and does not depend on the activities life cycle. If you plan on
>   keeping long-lived objects that need a context, remember the
>   application object.

Instead the *Activity Context* is associated with the activity and could be destroyed as many times as the activity is destroyed - changing screen orientation, back button etc.